# Need help to integrate Visual SVN Server [Enterprise] with Bugzilla

Tags: svn, bugzilla, visualsvn-server

I am running windows 7 32 bit.

My requirement is to, integrate the `Visual SVN Server [Enterprise]` edition with Bugzilla.
I have bugzilla up and running, now when the dev team commits a code change, `logs/events/tags` provided by them should get reflected against the bug id against which the patch is deployed.

Please let me know if there are any `plug-ins/add-ons/hook` scripts available to integrate these two tools.

Regards,
Anand